# Issue with Session Expiration : Azure Thinktecture Identity Server Single sign on

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

Log In site designed  using  ThinkTecture Identity  server API. 
LogIn site and customer site are hosted as Azure WebRoles.

After successful Login, its redirecting to customer site. Here i am getting the Logged in user.

```
var emaild = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.
```

After few hours I checked the site, Still I was getting the logged In user. I dont know when this Current user session will get expired? If anyone knows please share your views.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session has by default the same lifetime as the initial token - which is 10 hours by default. You can change that in idsrv config.

Comment: You are right Its mentioned in IdentityServer config file.  <Setting name="SsoCookieLifetime" value="10" />. I dint know earlier.